# How to get the name of a specific quest in the Quest Log in WoW?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

I am scripting in Vanilla WoW - 1.12.1 and I can get the number of quests in the quest log using the following code:

```
local numEntries, numQuests = GetNumQuestLogEntries();
DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage(numQuests);
```

numQuests is the number of the quests in the Quest Log.

However, when I try to get the title of a specific quest in the list, I get the wrong quest title because the regions are included in the Quest Log:

```
local mtitle = GetQuestLogTitle(1);
DEFAULT_CHAT_FRAME:AddMessage(mtitle);
```

instead of getting the title of the first quest - "The Balance of the Nature", I get "Shadowglen" - because "Shadowglen" appears in the Quest Log list as the logs are grouped by region.

and then, when I try to get the name of the last quest in the quest log, the variable numQuests doesn't help. Because the function GetQuestLogTitle(n) doesn't return the name of the n-th quest, but it returns the name of the n-th line in the Quest Log.

Is there any function for getting the name of the n-th quest?

Or is there any function to count the number of lines in the quest log (including zones)?